# Connecting to database without running server in Apache Xindice

Tags: xml, java, xml-database

I am new to "Apache Xindice". I tried some examples from the internet and it
worked, but I have to run the server before running my applications.This allows it to connect to the database.

I don't want to run the server because my application runs locally
and I don't want to disturb the user with the server. I need to
connect to the database from my application only, the path of the
database is relative to the program.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, Apache Xindice seems to be out of date. The latest news entry was 2007.

There are some currently maintained embeddable XML databases like [Berkeley DB XML](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/berkeley-db/xml/index.html), [eXist](http://exist.sourceforge.net/) and [Qizx XML database engine](http://www.xmlmind.com/qizx/features.html). All of them also supports XQuery as the query language.